# Python split list if sequence of numbers is found

Tags: python, list

I've been trying to find a relevant question, though I can't seem to search for the right words and all I'm finding is how to check if a list contains an intersection.

Basically, I need to split a list once a certain sequence of numbers is found, similar to doing `str.split(sequence)[0]`, but with lists instead. I have working code, though it doesn't seem very efficient (also no idea if raising an error was the right way to go about it), and I'm sure there must be a better way to do it.

For the record, `long_list` could potentially have a length of a few million values, which is why I think iterating through them all might not be the best idea.

```
long_list = [2,6,4,2,7,98,32,5,15,4,2,6,43,23,95,10,31,5,1,73]
end_marker = [6,43,23,95]
end_marker_len = len(end_marker)

class SuccessfulTruncate(Exception):
    pass
try:
    counter = 0
    for i in range(len(long_list)):
        if long_list[i] == end_marker[counter]:
            counter += 1
        else:
            counter = 0
        if counter == end_marker_len:
            raise SuccessfulTruncate()
except SuccessfulTruncate:
    long_list = long_list[:2 + i - end_marker_len]
else:
    raise IndexError('sequence not found')

>>> long_list
[2,6,4,2,7,98,32,5,15,4,2]
```

Ok, timing a few answers with a big list of 1 million values (the marker is very near the end):

```
Tim: 3.55 seconds
Mine: 2.7 seconds
Dan: 0.55 seconds
Andrey: 0.28 seconds
Kasramvd: still executing :P
```

Comment: Instead of raising an exception and catching it in the same try/except you can just omit the try/except and do `if counter == end_marker_len: long_list = long_list[:2 + i - end_marker_len]`. *Sucessful* is not a word thats fitting for an exception name. Exceptions are used to indicate that something failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my solution used approach with `index` method:

```
input = [2,6,4,2,7,98,32,5,15,4,2,6,43,23,95,10,31,5,1,73]
brk = [6,43,23,95]
brk_len = len(brk)
brk_idx = 0
brk_offset = brk_idx + brk_len

try:
    while input[brk_idx:brk_offset] != brk:
        brk_idx = input.index(brk[0], brk_idx + 1)
        brk_offset = brk_idx + brk_len
except ValueError: 
    print("Not found")
else:
    print(input[:brk_idx])
```

Comment: @Peter since you can have millions of items in your list, I understand that in this case it might be, but remember that speed is generally not as important as short, understandable code

Comment: Yeah, I get your point, I usually do go for the shorter nicer looking stuff, but this is one of the very processing heavy parts of the code so I do ideally need the speed too :)

Answer (score 3):

> I have working code, though it doesn't seem very efficient (also no idea if raising an error was the right way to go about it), and I'm sure there must be a better way to do it.

I commented on the exception raising in my comment

> Instead of raising an exception and catching it in the same try/except you can just omit the try/except and do `if counter == end_marker_len: long_list = long_list[:2 + i - end_marker_len]`. Successful is not a word thats fitting for an exception name. Exceptions are used to indicate that something failed

Anyway, here is a shorter way:

```
>>> long_list = [2,6,4,2,7,98,32,5,15,4,2,6,43,23,95,10,31,5,1,73]
>>> end_marker = [6,43,23,95]
>>> index = [i for i in range(len(long_list)) if long_list[i:i+len(end_marker)] == end_marker][0]
>>> long_list[:index]
[2, 6, 4, 2, 7, 98, 32, 5, 15, 4, 2]
```

List comprehension inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10459493/find-indexes-of-sequence-in-list-in-python) post

Comment: Thanks, that's a much better way of going about it haha. I just also thought looking at yours, I could potentially find all the indexes of where the first number is, and only check onwards from those indexes :)

Answer (score 3):

As a more pythonic way instead of multiple slicing you can use `itertools.islice` within a list comprehension :

```
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> M,N=len(long_list),len(end_maker)
>>> long_list[:next((i for i in range(0,M) if list(islice(long_list,i,i+N))==end_marker),0)]
[2, 6, 4, 2, 7, 98, 32, 5, 15, 4, 2]
```

Note that since the default value of `next` function is 0 if it doesn't find any match it will returns the whole of `long_list`.

Comment: Thanks, that way is quite nice, I did just time it though and it unfortunately takes about twice as long as Tims answer :P

Comment: @Peter For small lists like this you are right but for larger lists my answer will performs pretty much better

Comment: Ah ok, going to test out a larger list now anyways

Comment: Hmm, it's not coping so well with larger lists, been going for like a minute and still not finished aha.

Answer (score 1):

If the values are of limited range, say fit in bytes (this can also be adapted to larger types), why not then encode the lists so that the string method `find` could be used:

```
long_list = [2,6,4,2,7,98,32,5,15,4,2,6,43,23,95,10,31,5,1,73]
end_marker = [6,43,23,95]

import struct

long_list_p = struct.pack('B'*len(long_list), *long_list)
end_marker_p = struct.pack('B'*len(end_marker), *end_marker)

print long_list[:long_list_p.find(end_marker_p)]
```

Prints:

```
[2, 6, 4, 2, 7, 98, 32, 5, 15, 4, 2]
```

I tried using `bytes` as in but the find method they had didn't work:

```
print long_list[:bytes(long_list).find(bytes(end_marker))]
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks, this one is the fastest so far, I'll give it a shot on a very long list and see if it still holds up :)