# Finding consecutive patterns in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pattern-matching

How can I use python to find consecutive occurrence of a pattern? For example in `['a','b','a','b','c']`, we have 2 consecutive 'ab's, so it occurred twice. `['a', 'b', 'a']` does not contain consecutive pattern.

I wrote a function which can only count the occurrence of a pattern, but not necessarily consecutive occurrence

```
def get_occur(list, seq):
    return ''.join(list).count(''.join(seq))
```

Comment: Do you mean one specific pattern?

Comment: Find the first occurrence of `seq` and check if `list[index + len(seq):]` starts with the same sequence. If not, find the next occurrence, rinse and repeat. Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10459493/find-indexes-of-sequence-in-list-in-python) to find the index of a sublist.

Comment: Are you looking for a specific pattern, or _any_ pattern?

Comment: I am looking at specific pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just like to point out that if you are literally trying to find repeating patterns in strings, you should use the [re builtin](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

Building on what @Selcuk said in his comment,

```
l = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
print(l)

def consec_pattern(lst, pvs):
    # recursively return number of consecutive times pvs (previous pattern)
    # occurs in lst (list)

    if len(lst) < len(pvs):
        return 0 # no occurances of pvs in lst

    if lst[:len(pvs)] == pvs:  # if pvs is found at the start of lst
        shorter = lst[len(pvs):]
        return consec_pattern(shorter, pvs) + 1
    return 0  # if this is not the case, return 0

print(consec_pattern(l, [*'ab']))

# we can now annotate the list with number of occurances
l = [*'xababcd']
print(*l)
for i in range(len(l)):
    # take an element off of l each time you call to find
    # the value for the next position
    print(consec_pattern(l[i:], [*'ab']), end=' ')
print()
```

This is an O(n) solution if you want the consecutive occurances of a specific sublist, and could be used to find occurances of all sublists but there is probably a much more efficient way to do it if you need all sublists consecutive occurances.

**Edit**

Using Regular Expressions library you can use the search function

```
import re
string = 'xababcdab'
pattern = 'ab'

match = re.search(f'({pattern})+', string)
start, end = match.span()
consecutive_matches = (end-start)//len(pattern)
print(consecutive_matches)  # outputs 2
```